# I am using dialog.ask with the yes or no options...I want it to auto highlight 'yes' instead of 'no' when it pops up, how?

Tags: java, blackberry, dialog

I'd like to have the dialog box popup with the 'yes' auto highlighted instead of 'no' in case people don't read and just click. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dialog.ask()` has several overloaded versions available which have a `defaultChoice` parameter, for example:

```
Dialog.ask(Dialog.D_YES_NO, "Continue?", Dialog.YES);
```